# How to show a html button for asp:button click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net web page with asp:button control. I need to show two (normal) HTML buttons for the click event of the asp:button control. 
My requirement is when the page load for the first time there will be only asp:button there visible. After I click on that asp:button other two HTML buttons should be visible. But they should be visible for all the other postbacks. I mean if there would be any post backs, that HTML buttons should be visible constantly. How could I do that? Please help me. I tried to implement that using jquery hide and show.

Comment: show the code you tried to implement, using jquery should be what you want.  why didn't it work?

Comment: Can you please post your code, especially how youused JQuery hide and show. Why not using server asp:button for the other two buttons?

Comment: I need to use plain html buttons because I need to show a slider effect using jquery, show in an animated way smoothly. If I used an asp:button the page make a post back and the animation would be a mess.

Comment: I think JQuery hide and show will do it for you. It will be easy to for people to help if you post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<asp:Button>` controls for the other two buttons, and can set Visible="false" initially, then setting Visible="true" when you need to show them.  This way, the server can do everything, and retain viewstate too so you don't have to reshow the buttons every time the page posts back.

ASP buttons are standard buttons but can trigger the functionality you want through the OnClientClick property:

```
<asp:Button .. UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Move up" OnClientClick="moveSlider(1);return false;" />
<asp:Button .. UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Move down" OnClientClick="moveSlider(-1);return false;" />
```

Using `return false;` makes sure that the button doesn't postback, and UseSubmitbehavior="false" renders an `<input type='button' />` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I just need that two plain html buttons because I need to make a jquery animation when each button is clicked. If I use asp:button control it makes a post back and the animation becomes a mess. That's why I need html buttons.

Comment: That's what I'm saying though, the OnClickClick prevents the postback as defined above.  So there is no postback.  But if you want standard HTML buttons, I'd define an <input type="button" runat="server", which allows you to muck with its properties on the server and refer to it by ID.